# MongoDB query string with ISODate from the angular front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, get, query-string

I have a mongoDB model query Model.find(query) that I want to use in a flexible way. My idea was to pass in any object that might be needed to find particular instances of the model. In my case, I am looking for instances before a given date, such as:

`db.model.find({"date": {"$lt": ISODate('2016-02-11T19:00:38.702Z')}})`

This code works flawlessly. The problem I am having is the creation/stringifying of the same. At the front end, I would do something like:

`{date: {$lt: 'ISODate("'(new Date()).toISOString()+'")'}}`

The problem is that ISODate needs to be in the query without quotation marks. Any clue on how to transmit this query in a GET request?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to send the `Date` string to the server where you can convert it to an `ISODate`:

From the client:

```
// 1. stringify the date
var currentDate = (new Date()).toISOString();
// 2. send the date in a request
// This example sends the string via the query parameter 'currentDate'
```

On the server:

```
db.model.find({"date": {"$lt": ISODate(req.query.currentDate)}})
```

Comment: I would like to send the complete query from the front end, as I would use it as a filter, so that would not work, right?